# how to flip margin watermark in a two sided document

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I have a problem that i didn't figure out how to solve it.
I want that the background flips each time we turn the page.
This way pair pages will have the background margin on the left , and the impair pages will have the background margin photo at right. 
I wish i was clear.

```
\usepackage{background} %see the background doc for more info

\backgroundsetup{%  
  scale=1,       
  angle=0,       
  opacity=.7,    
  color =black,  
  contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at ([yshift=0cm,xshift=-9.7cm]current page) {\includegraphics[scale=1.10]{Margin.png}};    
\end{tikzpicture}}  
}
```

Comment: The package documentation contains an example of this.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina i did read the background doc..

Help me if you can please...

Comment: Please see my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example 4 of the package documentation explains how to achieve this. The idea is to use a conditional test (adjust the position and content according to your specific needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=1,scale=1]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifodd\value{page}\relax%
\backgroundsetup{% settings for odd-numbered pages
  angle=90,
  position={1.35\textwidth,-0.5\textheight},%
  contents={\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}}
  }%
\else
\backgroundsetup{% settings for even-numbered pages
  angle=270,
  position={0,-0.5\textheight},%
  contents={\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}}
}%
\fi%
\BgMaterial}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To leave out the background material for the first pages, you can use another conditional; something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=1,scale=1]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifnum\value{page}>3
\ifodd\value{page}\relax%
\backgroundsetup{% settings for odd-numbered pages
  angle=90,
  position={1.35\textwidth,-0.5\textheight},%
  contents={\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}}
  }%
\else
\backgroundsetup{% settings for even-numbered pages
  angle=270,
  position={0,-0.5\textheight},%
  contents={\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}}
}%
\fi%
\BgMaterial
\fi}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can we suppress the waterwark from the first pages.. \NoBgThispage doesn't work anymore??

Comment: I tried the value{page}>3 but it doesn't work

Comment: @luke please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @GonzaloMedina but the first pages are in numeroted in romain... and i just want to suppress the margin background in  the I and II page...

Comment: @luke change `3` to `2` in `\ifnum\value{page}>3`